# object detection with weight of Tiny Yolo

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am going to use TinyYolo model for object detection. In fact, I want to use the weights of this model. In order to do it, I downloaded this weight from the website and then applied the bottom codes to implement. First I introduced TinyYoloNet, then I defined the function for using weights. Also I used Pytorch framework.

```
class TinyYoloNet(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(TinyYoloNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_classes = 20  # VOC PASCAL
        self.anchors = [1.08,1.19,  3.42,4.41,  6.63,11.38,  9.42,5.11,  16.62,10.52]
        self.num_anchors = len(self.anchors) / 2
        num_output = (5 + self.num_classes) * self.num_anchors
        
        # 7 x 7 feature map
        self.width = 224  
        self.height = 224
        
        # loss function
        self.loss = YoloLoss(self.num_classes, self.anchors, self.num_anchors)

        # Convultional Neural Network
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            # conv1 
            # conv2
            # conv3
            # conv4
            # conv5
            # conv6
            # conv7
            # conv8
            ('conv8', nn.Conv2d(1024, 1024, 3, 1, 1, bias=False)),
            ('bn8', nn.BatchNorm2d(1024)),
            ('leaky8', nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True)),

            # output: 125 = 5 * (4 + 1 + 20)
            ('output', nn.Conv2d(1024, 125, 1, 1, 0))
        ]))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn(x)
        return x


def load_model(weights):
    '''
    load model 
    '''
    model = TinyYoloNet()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights))
    return model.cuda() if use_gpu else model

model = load_model(weights='weights/yolov2-tiny-voc.weights')
```

**Eventually, I received the following error**

[image]

I know the problem is about `torch.load`. I do not fix this error. On the other hand, in this error, it was mentioned the problem will fix by improve the python version.

My python version is 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Darknet weights cannot be loaded in pytorch straight away. If you intent to use darknet weights. The easiest way is you can refer to [readFromDarknet function in OpenCV DNN module](https://learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/). It's an opencv dnn module which allows you to load darknet weights quite easily.

Please do remember to load darknet weights, you need to have `.cfg` file. Which carries to carry details of layers for the weights.